# how to remove single data among similar data, from array at a time?

Tags: javascript, function, filter

```
const deletItem=(id)=>{
        setCart(cart.filter(product=>product.id !== id))
        console.log(id);
    }
```

here when i  want to delet single product all similar product id get deleted at a time ... how can I fix this .

Comment: Since you said it's deleting all similar product ids, it definitely sounds like your array has several items with the same id (which is supposed to be a unique, non-repeated identifier), and that's why you're filtering more than one.

Comment: yes, i have several items with the same ID  because I can choose the same product in more than one piece. (my product id is hardcoded that's why every time same ID attached with the product when the user choose )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think array `splice` is better used to delete an item from an array. Only you need to find the `indexOf` first.

```js
var cart = [
  {name: 'product a', id: 1},
  {name: 'product b', id: 1},
  {name: 'product c', id: 2},
]  
const deleteItem = (id) => {
  var pos = cart.map(x => x.id).indexOf(id);
  if (pos >= 0) {
    cart.splice(pos, 1)
  }
}


deleteItem(1);
console.log(cart)
```

Comment: exactly this doesn't work on my project but it navigates me to think others' way.